# Validating XML against XSD when XSD changes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

Lets suppose I have an `XSD` schema named `xsd1`. Assume that a generated class looks like

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create a new schema `xsd2` which is almost the same as xsd1. It has only one more element `Prop3` of type `int`. Then `ClassA` changes to

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I serialize an instance of `ClassA` to XML, validation against `xsd1` fails with message

*Invalid child element 'Prop3'*

How can I have both validations succeed? I don't want two separate classes.

### Update

Serialized object

```
var a = new ClassA() { Prop1 = "p1", Prop2 = "p2" };
```

looks like

```
<ClassA>
    <Prop1>p1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>p2</Prop2>
</ClassA>
```

when I add `Prop3` to `ClassA` then the serialized object `a` becommes

```
<ClassA>
    <Prop1>p1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>p2</Prop2>
    <Prop3>0</Prop3>
</ClassA>
```

and as so not valid against schema `xsd1`. When validating against `xsd1` I want only `Prop1` and `Prop2` to be serialized.

Comment: How are you serializing/deserializing the XML?

Comment: I use `XmlSerializer` class to convert an object to XML.

Comment: If one XSD says that it must contain `Prop1`, `Prop2`, and nothing else, and the other says it must contain `Prop1`, `Prop2`, `Prop3`, and nothing else, it's impossible to write an XML file that satisfies both. Is that what you're trying to do? Please explain.

Comment: Seems that the problem does not occur if `Prop3` is of type `string`

Answer (score 0):

Your question resembles a schema versioning question where you seek both forward and backward compatibility while adding a new element.  That is simply not possible.

Adding an optional element allows XML that was valid against XSD<sub>1</sub> to continue to be valid with the new version, XSD<sub>2</sub>.  That part is fine.  However, any XML that includes the optional new element will not be valid against the original version, XSD<sub>1</sub>.

### Update

> When I publish a new schema, clients need time to adapt their code.

Fair enough -- a common requirement.

> Our clients sends us data (objects, not xml)

That's backward from recommended best practices.

> they determine against which schema should it be validated

Then either honor their commitment (rather than trying to defeat it) by supporting both XSDs during transition, or build in flexibility to your XSDs via liberal mechanisms such as `xsd:any`.  It's up to you, but *you cannot expect validation be both strict and liberal simultaneously.*

Comment: Our clients sends us data (objects, not xml) and they determine against which schema should it be validated. I just want that the new added property does not spoil validation against `xsd1`. When I publish a new schema, clients need time to adapt their code. And till then send data must be valid against `xsd1`. Se my update. Hope I was clear enough.